# Java JDK - possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, integer

So I have recently written the following code:

```java
Scanner money = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please type in the type of ticket you would like to buy.\nA. Child B. Adult C. Elder.");
String type = money.next();
System.out.print("Now please type in the amount of tickets you would like to buy.");
int much = money.nextInt();
int price = 0;
switch (type) {
    case "A":
        price = 10;
        break;
    case "B":
        price = 60;
        break;
    case "C":
        price = 35;
        break;
    default:
        price = 0;
        System.out.print("Not a option ;-;");
}
if (price != 0) {
    int total2 = price * much * 0.7;
    System.out.print("Do you have a coupon code? Enter Y or N");
    String YN = money.next();
    if (YN.equals("Y")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your coupon code.");
        int coupon = money.nextInt();
        if (coupon == 21) {
            System.out.println("Your total price is " + "$" + total2 + ".");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid coupon code, your total price is " + "$" + price* much + ".");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Your total price is " + "$" + price* much + "." ); 
    }
}
money.close();
```

When I try and run it with cmd, it keeps displaying this:

> TrainTicket.java:31: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
> at `int total2 = price * much * 0.7`

Can someone help and explain the error that I have made?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you convert `double` to `int`, the precision of the value is lost. For example, when you convert 4.8657 (double) to int, the int value will be 4. Primitive `int` does not store decimal numbers, so you will lose 0.8657.

In your case, 0.7 is a double value (floating point treated as double by default unless mentioned as float - 0.7f). When you calculate `price*much*0.7`, the answer is a double value and so the compiler wouldn't allow you to store it in a type integer since there could be a loss of precision. That's what is *"possible lossy conversion"*, you may lose precision.

So what could you do about it? You need to tell the compiler that you really want to do it. You need to tell it that you know what you are doing. So explicitly convert double to int using the following code:

```
int total2= (int) (price*much*0.7);
 /*(int) tells compiler that you are aware of what you are doing.*/
 //also called as type casting
```

In your case,since you are calculating the cost, I'll suggest you to declare variable `total2` as the type double or float.

```
double total2=price*much*0.7;
 float total2=price*much*0.7;
 //will work
```

Comment: @billc.cn amount is usually expressed in decimals and that's the reason I suggested it!

Comment: I meant to say use doubles instead of floats.... floats lose precision too quickly to be useful for even every day cases.

Comment: Note it needs to be `int total2 = (int) (price*much*0.7);`. Otherwise, the `(int)` is applied to `price`, not the result of the expression.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to assign `price* much* 0.7`, which is a floating point value (a `double`), to an integer variable. A `double` is not an exact integer, so in general an `int` variable cannot hold a `double` value.

For instance, suppose the result of your calculation is `12.6`. You can't hold `12.6` in an integer variable, but you could cast away the fraction and just store `12`.

If you are not worried about the fraction you will lose, cast your number to an `int` like this:

```
int total2 = (int) (price* much* 0.7);
```

Or you could round it to the nearest integer.

```
int total2 = (int) Math.round(price*much*0.7);
```