# I keep getting this error: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, error-handling

I get this error with a little arrow pointing at decimal integers. Are decimals allowed? What do I have to write to make decimals acceptable? This is my code:

```
public class BinarySearch {
public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

    public static int search(int[] arr, int searchValue) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = arr.length - 1;
        return binarySearch(arr, searchValue, left, right);
    }

    private static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int searchValue, int left, int right) {
        if (right < left) {
            return NOT_FOUND;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
        if (searchValue > arr[mid]) {
            return binarySearch(arr, searchValue, mid + 1, right);
        } else if (searchValue < arr[mid]) {
            return binarySearch(arr, searchValue, left, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return mid;
        }       
    }
}

import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println(BinarySearch.search(arr, 2));
    }
}
```

The error is this:

9: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        int[] arr = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};

^

9: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        int[] arr = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};

^

2 errors

Comment: Duplicate of [possible lossy conversion from double to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396577/java-jdk-possible-lossy-conversion-from-double-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int[] arr = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};
```

in main is creating an array of doubles (e,g, 10.5) and you're casting to an int[].  If you change the type to double[] then everything should work.  These are the lines to change:

```
public static int search(int[] arr, int searchValue) {

private static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int searchValue, int left, int right) 

int[] arr = {-3, 10, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store doubles in the array of ints (you can cast these double values to int, but you lose precision that way). You can change your code to make it work with `double[]` instead of `int[]` and then everything should work correctly. Just replace `int[]` with `double[]` everywhere you used it in your code.